# How to ensure a Json file conforms to a pre-defined structure?

Tags: json, ansible

I want to take a JSON file as input to a playbook and ensure that it has specific attributes/keys in a specific structure. Let's say this is saved in a variable called `{{ json }}`. Here's an example of what the JSON should look like:

```json
{
  "my_json": {
    "version": 2,
    "previous_version": 1,
    "some_things": ["thing1", "thing2"],
    "more_things": {
      "path": "file1.txt",
      "list_of_objs": [
        {
          "regex": "^.*$",
          "aws_path": "path/to/file.txt"
        },
        {
          "regex": "^\d*$",
          "aws_path": "path/to/file2.txt"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that all the key names of the above JSON exist in the same structure. I can do this in this way by manually specifying each key that should exist:

```yaml
- assert:
    that:
      - json[item] is defined
  loop:
    - my_json

- assert:
    that:
      - json.my_json[item] is defined
  loop:
    - version
    - previous_version
    - some_things
    - more_things

- assert:
    that:
      - json.my_json.more_things[item] is defined
  loop:
    - path
    - list_of_objs
```

This method "works", but it's not very scalable when the JSON gets more complex and I don't like hard-coding a list of all the keys that should be there, plus I'll have to do a separate task for every level.

Is there a way to provide simply a template and check that the input JSON has all the same keys at the same levels? Or is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: What you describe very closely looks like what [json schéma](https://json-schema.org/) offers.

Comment: so how would I incorporate that in an ansible task?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/validate_module.html

Comment: Perfect, that sounds exactly like what I'm looking for